# Automatic RDP connection on boot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, remote, rdp

I'm attempting to make multiple thinclients using pi 3's to interact with a Windows program.

So, using Remoteapp on windows 10 I've tried using freerdp and remmina to RDP to a windows machine but I cannot get a Remoteapp .rdp file to show only the application.

I'd also like to have the pi automatically connect after booting and attempt to restart the connection if the remote session ends for any reason.